# Using the Code Coverage devtool by selenium+maven automation?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

Is it possible to use the Code Coverage devtool (from upcoming Chrome release) by selenium+maven automation?

E.g. like JaCoCo for java projects?

I.e. I imagine approximately such scenario for our web-product:

There is a test suite with several test cases.

- The Chrome Code Coverage collection is enabled somehow from outside
- Then test suite is executed (by maven):
  The each test case uses Selenium to run Chrome browser, executes testing scenario and close the webdriver (browser is closed).
- Then, after the suite is finished the code coverage data (CSS/JS related) could be collected and could be viewed as a report later.