# chrome extract coverage report as part of build process

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, build, code-coverage

in chrome you can generate a coverage report of the css and js used, how can i get this report during my build process in order to automatically split and load my files accordingly? (coverage report without any interactions with the website).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mean on this practice as usefull at all, i'll explain:

if you are using dynamic content this will break the styling of your dynamic elements or your dynamic elements itself.

The best way i found to deal with this is using parcel js as package manager and properly set your js and scss into each .html for each component on your view. This will create a "vitual tree" of styles for each view and will create an insert a js and css on each view. Of course you may get some extra css and js, depending on your needs and your best practices.

- For dynamic content: if you are in a view that can create dynamically an element, you'll need to preload its js and css alongside with the rest of css and js even if the user does not interact with the element that will create this other element dynamically.
- For static content: If you're working with static content, then parcel.js and write your css and js specifically for each view will be the way to go.
  There's no much point on scrape the coverage and take what you need now, as you can work with best practices in development time.

If you want to do that anyway, you can do this with [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) (`npm i puppeteer --save`).

```
  (async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  //Start sending raw DevTools Protocol commands are sent using `client.send()`
  //First off enable the necessary "Domains" for the DevTools commands we care about
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()
  await client.send('Page.enable')
  await client.send('DOM.enable')
  await client.send('CSS.enable')

  const inlineStylesheetIndex = new Set();
  client.on('CSS.styleSheetAdded', stylesheet => {
    const { header } = stylesheet
    if (header.isInline || header.sourceURL === '' || header.sourceURL.startsWith('blob:')) {
      inlineStylesheetIndex.add(header.styleSheetId);
    }
  });

  //Start tracking CSS coverage
  await client.send('CSS.startRuleUsageTracking')

  await page.goto(`http://localhost`)
  // const content = await page.content();
  // console.log(content);

  const rules = await client.send('CSS.takeCoverageDelta')
  const usedRules = rules.coverage.filter(rule => {
    return rule.used
  })

  const slices = [];
  for (const usedRule of usedRules) {
    // console.log(usedRule.styleSheetId)
    if (inlineStylesheetIndex.has(usedRule.styleSheetId)) {
      continue;
    }

    const stylesheet = await client.send('CSS.getStyleSheetText', {
      styleSheetId: usedRule.styleSheetId
    });

    slices.push(stylesheet.text.slice(usedRule.startOffset, usedRule.endOffset));
  }

  console.log(slices.join(''));

  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106841/chrome-devtools-coverage-how-to-save-or-capture-code-used-code)

Comment: its a static website, a single html file and a few css an js files, all written by myself, no components, no librarys - Even though probably not necessary, I would like to know how to do it.