# how to get all the styles applied to particular element?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for an easier way to get all the styles applied to a particular element so that I can re-use them in my project.

I've checked the chrome tool and there is lots of clutter on the right side of the selected element.

Is there any extension or hack to get styles for an element quickly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Switch to the `Computed` panel on the right.

Comment: how to check what's inside weird class names used like "Igw0E", "eGOV_", isn't good practice to use meaningful class names ? Note: I am begineer to FE dev

Comment: Sounds like [Chrome Devtools Coverage: how to save or capture code used code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45106841)